# Definition of graded abelian group

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

I am reading *Homology Theory* by Vick, and in this book a graded abelian group $G$ is defined to be a “collection of abelian groups {$G_i$} indexed by the integers with component-wise operation”.

What are the elements of $G$ and what is the operation on it turning it to a group? Does the author mean that $G$ is the direct product of $G_i$’s for “component-wise operation” to make sense?

Comment: >Does the author mean that $G$ is the direct product of $G_i$’s for “component-wise operation” to make sense?

Yes, this is exactly what they mean: $G = \bigoplus_{i \in \mathbb Z} G_i$.

Comment: @AlexProvost thanks, but your notation is not direct product, it is weak direct product or direct sum.

Comment: Right, direct sum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, graded objects are the direct sums of their components. (In algebraic topology, for example when looking at the homology of a space, one almost never adds elements from different homogeneous pieces, so in such cases you can almost think of it like the disjoint union of the different components. But it's really the direct sum.)

Comment: Thanks, in the sequel to this definition and finding the homology of a singleton as the simplest example I realized that really we can think of it as the disjoint union of components as you said

Answer (score 0):

For the graded group $G$, an element $g \in G$ is of the form $g=g_1+ \ldots + g_n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. This turns out that $G$ is an abelian group with the addition. Yes, $G$ is the (internal) direct product of $G_i$’s for component-wise addition.

Comment: What you have written is not a direct product, it’s a weak direct product or direct sum.